# How to properly move a mariadb database from a container to the host

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I have a smallish webapp running in a Docker container.  It uses a mariadb database running in another container on the same box, based on the official "mariadb" image.

When I first set up these containers, I started the mariadb container using an "internal" database.  I gave the "/var/lib/mysql" a volume name, but I didn't map it to a directory on the host ("-v vol-name:/var/lib/mysql").  Actually, I'm not even sure why I gave it a volume name.  I set this up several months ago, and I'm not sure why I would have done that specifically.

In any case, I've concluded that having a database internal to the container wasn't a good idea.  I've decided I really need to have the actual database stored on the host and use a volume mapping to refer to it.  I know how to do this if I was setting this up from scratch, but now that the app is running, I need to move the database to the host and restart the container to point to that.  I'm not certain of all the proper steps to make this happen.

In addition, I'm also going to need to set up a second instance of this application, using containers based on the same images.  The second database will also be stored on the host, in a directory next to the other one.  I can initialize the second db with the backup file from the first one, but I'll likely manually empty most of the tables in the second instance.

I did use mysqldump inside the container to dump the database, then I copied that backup file to the host.

I know how to set a volume mapping in "docker run" to map /var/lib/mysql in the container to a location on the host.

At this point, I'm not certain exactly what to do with this backup file so I can restart the container with the modified volume mapping.  I know I can run "mysql dbname < backup.sql", but I'm not sure of the consequences of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the container is running, run [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)`-a CONTAINER:/var/lib/mysql /local/path/to/folder` to copy the MariaDB databases from the container to your local machine. Replace "CONTAINER" with the name or ID of your MariaDB container.

Once you've done that, you can stop the container and restart it binding `/local/path/to/folder` to the container's `/var/lib/mysql` path.

If you're using an older version of docker that does not support the `-a` or `--archive` flag, you can copy the files without that flag but you'll need to make sure that the folder on the host machine has the proper ownership: the UID and GID of the folder must match the UID and GID of the folder in the Docker container.

Note: if you're using SELinux, you might need to set the proper permissions as well, as the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) for the MariaDB image states:

> Note that users on host systems with SELinux enabled may see issues with this. The current workaround is to assign the relevant SELinux policy type to the new data directory so that the container will be allowed to access it:
>
> `$ chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /my/own/datadir`

Comment: When I run my command based on this, I get "unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a".  I checked the man page for "docker-cp", and it says "The cp command behaves like the Unix cp -a command in that  directories are  copied  recursively with permissions preserved if possible." There is no mention of a "-a" option to "docker cp".

Comment: Try the full form (`--archive`). The documentation states: "Files copied to the local machine are created with the UID:GID of the user which invoked the `docker cp` command. However, if you specify the `-a` option, `docker cp` sets the ownership to the user and primary group at the source." This will be required to make it work when you map the local folder back later.

Comment: "unknown flag: --archive". Note that this is "Docker version 1.12.6, build 96d83a5/1.12.6".

Comment: Ah. You can try without the `-a`/`--archive` option, but you might need to fix file ownership manually. But you should consider upgrading to a more recent version, after 1.13 they switched to a different versioning scheme which is now at 17.06

Comment: Ok. After the copy, what do I do to properly fix file permissions?  I know how to use chown and chmod.  The files in the container are owned by mysql:mysql, and the files on the host are owned by "m84796:m84796" (that name is a service account used to run the containers). There is no "mysql" user on the host.  Do I have to somehow map userids from the container to the host?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr The UID and GID must match. You can set those with `chown` just like you would a username/groupname

Comment: I assume the thing that has to match are the numbers, not the names?  It appears the uid and gid of "mysql" on the container are numbers that are already in use by existing users and groups on the host. I assume that's a problem?  I suppose I could just chown using the numbers, but I would have preferred to create a mysql group and user on the host with the same numbers.

Comment: The numbers have to match. It's not a problem if they are in use by other groups on the host machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153057/discussion-between-david-m-karr-and-rickdenhaan).